# Comments in argument lists?

Tags: rsync

Some commands, such as `rsync`, take in lists as an argument. Can these files contain unix comments like `#`?

Answer (score 6):

Unless the documentation for the command explicitly mentions that it can contain comments, assume that it cannot.

Comment: Concur. Generally, the respective manpage of the command will detail whether you can add comments to a read file, and if so how it identifies a line as a comment.

Answer (score 3):

What I usually do in cases like this, is build an arguments array (which can take comments) and then pass those along to rsync, for instance.

```
#!/bin/bash
rsync_args=(
    # Show me what you're doing
    --itemize-changes
    # All HTML and resources
    *.html *.css *.js
    # All PHP source code
    *.php
    # To the live server
    live:
)
rsync "${rsync_args[@]}";
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to add comments about files in the file list. This is not possible, because when shell encounters the # character, it will ignore all remaining character on the command line. One way to achieve this is to use rsync with --files-from=filelist argument. The filelist file can contain comments.

On the other hand, if you want to embed # characters in the filename, then this will work. For example, with bash:

```
touch a#b 
touch 'a #b' 
touch "a #b"
```

Comment: See e.g. the `--include-from` argument of `rsync`.

Answer (score 0):

*Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams* answer is the safest, but if you really want to do it (as I do in some instances), a simple workaround can easily get at least part-way there by dealing with `# comments` which take up the entire line.

Things can get a bit gnarly if you want to  handle comments which follow the real list data-lines, unless you are certain that your data-lines contain no embedded `#` chars.

You can use [process substitution](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/shell-process-redirection) and a simple helper script.

Here are some examples.  The `grc` before `diff` generates coloured output.
I've used bash functions, but you can, of course, save them to a script file.

```
# nocom handles comment-only lines (ie. no dat)
#       it ignores any # chars embedded in your data lines.
#
  nocom() { sed -e '/^[[:space:]]*#/d' "$1"; }

# NOCOM handles handles comments which occurr after your data   
#       as well as comment-only lines.  
#       Do not use NOCM unless you are CERTAIN that your data
#       lines contain no  # chars.
#
  NOCOM() { sed -n '/^[[:space:]]*#/d; s/^\([^#][^#]*[^[:space:]]\)[[:space:]]*#.*/\1/; p' "$1"; }

printf '# a bit of hokus-pokus
        # you see the coments here, 
        # but the calling program will not.
$HOME/bin/abra
$HOME/bin/kadabra  # comment after data
$HOME/bin/sim# another comment after data
' >file

echo == nocom ==
cat <(nocom "file")
echo == NOCOM ==
cat <(NOCOM "file")
echo == diff ==
grc diff "file" <(NOCOM "file")
```

Here is the output:

```
== nocom ==
$HOME/bin/abra
$HOME/bin/kadabra  # comment after data
$HOME/bin/sim# another comment after data
== NOCOM ==
$HOME/bin/abra
$HOME/bin/kadabra
$HOME/bin/sim
== diff ==
1,3d0
< # a bit of hokus-pokus
<         # you see the coments here, 
<         # but the calling program won't.
5,6c2,3
< $HOME/bin/kadabra  # comment after data
< $HOME/bin/sim# another comment after data
---
> $HOME/bin/kadabra
> $HOME/bin/sim
```